# Which would be the best design pattern in Unity for this problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I have a black object that supplies power to purple ones. Purples can't connect with each other without the power coming from the black one. Also there is a range parameter decides whether connect or not. I'm just learning about design patterns and I want to know which one would be better in this situation. Can you suggest me a pattern to use? I'm using line renderer for the connections by the way.

Picture below is just a representation of the game, the actual game will be 3d.

[image: this might help to understand the idea]

The actual game looks like this. Dark purple one is the power supplier and the pink ones are conductors that are rotating around the yellow object and can be put on the grid cells one by one.
[image]

Comment: Does your Purple ones connect automatically if they are [Powered] and [In Range]? Because if that is the case there is a very elegant solution to this. Also can you post your purple Dot and Black dot code?

Comment: Yes, they connect automatically and also their location can be changed dynamically. I don't have a decent code right now, once I have a solution for the design I'm going to start coding.

Comment: `I've tried applying observer pattern, but didn't work` .. what exactly have you tried, what exactly does `didn't work` mean?

Comment: I'm just learning about design patterns and I don't know if the observer is the right one so, I wanted to know which one would be better in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't looking for a design pattern. You are looking for an Algorithm. Below is one I use for pathfinding in Unity. You'll have to adapt it a bit to suite your specific code.

https://github.com/Cornelis-Personal/AStar_CSharp

It is called the A* (A Star) Algorithm and it is very common with these sorts of problems.